# Passing array values as function parameter

Tags: javascript, parameters

Hi I am trying to write code for an image to change every second depending  on what is stored in an array.
Heres what I have so far:

```
function parse_input(){
    //initializes the input_text and the text_array variables
    var input_text=document.getElementById('input_text').value;
    var text_array=[];
    //loops through input_text and if it is an alphanumeric character...pushes it to the text_array
    for(var letter in input_text){
        const LETTER_REGEX=/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;

        if(LETTER_REGEX.test(input_text[letter])){
            text_array.push(input_text[letter]);
        }
    }
    //function to change the image
    function change_image(array){
            document.getElementById('letter_image').src="images/"+array+".png";
            document.getElementById('letter_image').alt=array;
    }
    //supposed to loop through the text_array and change the image every second.
    for(var i=0;i<text_array.length;i++){
        setTimeout(function(){change_image(text_array[i])},1000*i);
    }
}


window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById('finger_spell_it').onclick=function(){
        parse_input();
    }
}
```

When I go to run the test I get an undefined variable. I don't know what I am doing wrong please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your `setTimeout` runs, `i` is already at an undefined index.

You need to create a scope for it:

```
// ...

for(var i=0;i<text_array.length;i++){
    (function(index){
        setTimeout(function(){
            change_image(text_array[index])
        }, 1000 * index);
    })(i);
}

// ...
```

Comment: This helped me a lot thank you! I am not familiar with what you just did. can you tell me the name of the technique, so that I can look it up?

Comment: It is called a javascript closure @FrankieDee

Answer (score 0):

You need `closure`. This is elaborately explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/111200/1183010):

> That is a closure. A function doesn't have to return in order to be
>   called a closure. Simply accessing variables outside of your immediate
>   lexical scope creates a closure.
>
> ```
> function foo(x) {
>   var tmp = 3;
>   return function (y) {
>     alert(x + y + (++tmp));
>   }
> }
> var bar = foo(2); // bar is now a closure.
> bar(10);
> ```
>
> The above function will also alert 16, because bar can still refer to
>   x and tmp, even though it is no longer directly inside the scope.

for your code example:

```
for(var i=0;i<text_array.length;i++){
    (function(index){
        setTimeout(function(){
            change_image(text_array[index])
        }, 1000 * index);
    })(i);
}
```

closure can also be created using thirdparty tollboxes like jQuery [proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
for(var i=0;i<text_array.length;i++){
    setTimeout($.proxy(function(index){
            change_image(text_array[index])
        }, this, i)
    , 1000*i);
}
```

or using underscore.js [bind](http://underscorejs.org/#bind)

```
for(var i=0;i<text_array.length;i++){
    setTimeout(_.bind(function(index){
            change_image(text_array[index])
        }, this, i)
    , 1000*i);
}
```